# Regular expression for stock tickers - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of tweets. They look like this:

```
data = [['trading $aa $BB stock market info'],
        ['$aa is $116 market is doing well $cc $ABC']]
```

I want to extract stock tickers:

```
['$aa', '$BB']
['$aa', '$cc', '$ABC']]
```

I have tried this:

```
for i in data:
    print re.findall(r'[$]\S*', str(i))
```

And, the output contains $116 as well:

```
['$aa', '$BB']
['$aa', '$116', '$cc', '$ABC']]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want just letters instead, you could use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\S`. It depends on what your tickers are. You'll probably also want to use `+` instead of `*`, otherwise you'll match the dollar sign in front of a number, without the number.

Comment: If the tickers can contain numbers, but must contain at least one letter, you could use `\$(\d*[a-zA-Z]+\d*)+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match the dollar sign, one letter, and then anything that's not a space:

```
re.findall(r'[$][A-Za-z][\S]*', str(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

The package [**`reticker`**](https://pypi.org/project/reticker/) does this by creating a custom regular expression as per its configuration. It uses the created pattern to extract tickers from text. Alternatively, the returned pattern can be used independently.

```py
>>> import reticker

>>> extractor = reticker.TickerExtractor()
>>> type(extractor.pattern)
<class 're.Pattern'>

>>> reticker.TickerExtractor().extract("Comparing FNGU vs $WEBL vs SOXL- who wins? And what about $cldl vs $Skyu? BTW, will the $w+Z pair still grow? IMHO, SOXL is king! [V]isa is A-okay!")
["FNGU", "WEBL", "SOXL", "CLDL", "SKYU", "W", "Z", "V", "A"]

>>> reticker.TickerExtractor().extract("Which of BTC-USD, $ETH-USD and $ada-usd is best?\nWhat about $Brk.a and $Brk.B? Compare futures MGC=F and SIL=F.")
['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD', 'ADA-USD', 'BRK.A', 'BRK.B', 'MGC=F', 'SIL=F']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just leave this here for people looking for a regex that matches a stock ticker

```
re.fullmatch('([A-Za-z]{1,5})(-[A-Za-z]{1,2})?', symbol)
```